# How to force windows override file type association using Setup Project of Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I can associate the file types to my application exe very easily using Setup Deployment => View => File Types => in Visual Studio 2010. 
I set Name, Command, Extensions, Icon, etc. after googling.

I have tested it, and it works perfect but there is one thing that I want.

For example there is file name filename.ext , this file extension is not associate yet to any application, if I want to associate this extension to my application, it works perfectly but if I want to associate the file which is already associated to any other application then that extension files do not change their icon to mine application and they do not associate to my application automatically. 
The issue is to How to override the file association in windows using Visual Studio ?

How can I achieve this task that when I press finish button of the setup of my application then all files should be associated to my application automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: any one please ? is it so difficult ? :)